# How to pass data from php to chart.js

Tags: javascript, php, charts

I have a PHP array with this content:

```
[{"label":"Baden-Wuerttemberg","year":"1998","ins":"243812"}...] (34 entries).
```

Now I want to plot a chart with Chart.js in JS, but I don't know how to get the values for Labels and dataset.

This is what I have tried:

```
var jsArray = <?php echo json_encode($jsonArray); ?>;

    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
        title: {
            text: "My First Chart in CanvasJS"
        },
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            datasets: jsArray
        },

    });
    chart.render();
}
```

I want to plot on the `x` axis the year `Jahr` and on the `y` axis the total number `ins`.

Comment: It's best to use AJAX for PHP <-> JavaScript communication.

Comment: Have you tried : `JSON.parse('<?=$jsonArray;?>`? - The example you provided, is already `json encoded`, just pass it to js. When you ask a question about an error **ALWAYS** include the **error log**. Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your `php` script, what does it return?

Comment: nothing mate, still an empty screen. I tried it with `JSON.parse('<?=$jsonArray;?>` and the error reporting.

Answer (score 2):

`json_encode` function returns json encoded **string** but in the chart.js you would need json object. You just need to parse the string to object in javascript part like this:

```
var jsArray = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($jsonArray); ?>');
```

That should work!

---

#### Update

According to Chart.js documentation, each single object in `dataPoints` can have following properties:

```
{
    "label": "string, will appear if hovered the bar",
    "x": 10, // must be a number
    "y": 20 // must be a number
}
```

So you need to convert your data to have above format, something like this:

```
$formattedData = [];
foreach( $jsonArray as $data ) {
    $formattedData[] = [
        "label" => $data->Bundesland,
        "x"     => (int) $data->label,
        "y"     => (int) $data->sum
    ];
}
```

Then finally use the `$formattedData` like this:

```
var jsArray = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($formattedData); ?>');
```

There is no other problem in js part, only problem was the format of data.

Comment: Dont work, i get an empty screen. Here ist my code: (https://paste.ofcode.org/P2GULiw4WGAQHt2D8fkmx6)

Comment: You have a typo `type: type`, value should be a string. Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/7vgLmkoc/3/

Comment: i changed it to line but still empty screen. I have in my array 3 values as u can see in my post.

Comment: What is the type of your `$jsonArray` variable?

Comment: its an json object or not?

Comment: Yes. There are few other changes you need to make. I will update my answer, before that can you tell me how you want your chart to look like? What will be the x, and y ?

Comment: the x axis should be the years, y axis the total number "ins".
My data array is here: (https://paste.ofcode.org/tj5UH6HgPLHuw5vNKEVY53)
as u can see, i want for example plot a line chart for "Baden-Wuerttemberg", my next step than will be to select a nother country to plot